# How do i look for a combination of values in a dictionary that contains lists?

Tags: python

```
list_match= {"Mada":["yellow","green",],"Alexa":["blonde","brown"],"Sasha":["blue","readhead"],"Andreea":["cameleonic","brunett"]}

print ('welcome to the "Find your match quiz"')
print ("Let/'s begain")

eyes = input ("How should the eyes be?")
hair=input("How do you want the the hair to be?")

def cf(response,cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4):
    if response == (cond1):
        return response
    if response == (cond2):
        return response
    if response == (cond3):
        return response
    if response ==(cond4):
        return response
    else:
        return ("We don't have knowledge of this characteristic.")

cf(eyes,"green","brown","blue","cameleonic")
cf(hair,"yellow","blonde","readhead","brunett")
```

So...I want to make a little "Find your match" program.I decided to make a function that I can use for different characteristics that girls have..."Blonde" hair.... "blue" eyes...etc...
Well...the problem is that I don't know how to look for the combine results of the function:    cf(response,con1,cond2,cond3,cond4)    ,I want to combine this two results of the function:

```
cf(eyes,"green","brown","blue","cameleonic")
cf(hair,"yellow","blonde","readhead","brunett")
```

so I can look for the combination between the results in the above dictionary in order to get the key for each true combination that is in that dictionary,in the end printing the name of the girl plus the "You found a match" string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def search(*args):
    for (key, value) in list_match.items():
        if value == list(args):
            return key


>>> list_match= {"Mada":["yellow","green",],"Alexa":["blonde","brown"],"Sasha":["blue","readhead"],"Andreea":["cameleonic","brunett"]}
>>> search("cameleonic", "brunett")
'Andreea'
```

This will accept as many conditions as you want it to without having to add more and more `if` statements.

If you want to have it return multiple names, change the `return` into a `yield`. This will make a generator object, and you can print them by saying:

```
>>> list_match= {"Mada":["cameleonic","brunett"],"Alexa":["blonde","brown"],"Sasha":["blue","readhead"],"Andreea":["cameleonic","brunett"]}
>>> def search(*args):
    for (key, value) in list_match.items():
        if value == list(args):
            yield key
>>> ", ".join(name for name in search("cameleonic", "brunett"))
'Andreea, Mada'
```

If the order of the arguments does not matter:

```
def search(*args):
    for (key, value) in list_match.items():
       if sorted(value) == sorted(args):
           yield key
```

Comment: Your response put me another question...can I not use that       *args        can I use some other tipe of operator?As I can see from here the order of the argument matters,i just want to know if           "cameleonic" and "brunett" is in that dictionary,the order does not matter to me...

Answer (score 1):

Following list comprehension would give a list of names with matching attributes:

```
[k for k, v in list_match.items() if v[0] == eyes and v[1] = hair]
```

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail how the code works? Thank you.

Comment: The order does not appear to be set. You can't rely on eyes being at list index 0. Maybe a class would be better than a simple list of attributes. You could try "eyes in v and hair in v" as long as you don't mind the occasional overlap (matching brown eyes instead of brown hair). Also I would recommend an actual match function, to take that logic outside the dict comprehension. As for a detailed explanation of basic python syntax, look up "dict comprehension" at a tutorial or documentation site. (PS: the most attractive attribute is "likes me" then "is a good person," although looks are nice.)